# acf function in R return values

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to compute a simple `acf` in R. For example, consider:

```
v = acf(1:10, plot=F)
```

`v` now contains an element called `lag` which is a 3-dim array containing the last used in the estimation. How come this array is 3 dimensional and not simply 1 dimensional? I am asking because I would like to foresee exactly what will be in each dimension depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one column in your input data.

Try:

```
v = acf(data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10)), plot=F)
```

then you get an array. I believe this is used for multivariate time series

Comment: So then what is actually being returned? is it the full cross-correlation matrix? if so, what is the purpose of `ccf` then?

Comment: If you first set `x=rnorm(10)`, `y=rnorm(10)` and then do  `AC<-acf(c(x,y), plot=F)` and `CC<-ccf(x,y,plot=F)` you can compare the two outputs. The ccf results are part of the acf results. You can add more variables to the acf if you like. More than that I don't know.